# Regex match non-standard domains

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to regex match non-standard TLD's (domains that **do not** end with .com, .net or .org)

I've tried the following, but I'm doing something wrong.

```
.*(?<!\.(?:com|net|org)\/)

http://www.spam-link.br/getmoneyhere.php
```

My regex will match anything. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

https://regex101.com/r/HEbeWU/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://[^:/]++(?<!\.(?:com|net|org))
```